# What is ${command_} in a shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I have googled and found nothing. I am reading a shell script file and there there is this line

```
echo "docker run command"
echo ${command_}
```

What does this mean? Please notice that

1. there is an underscore after "command"
2. `command_` seems  not to be  defined elsewhere

Comment: What output are you seeing then? after `docker run command`? There must be something printed to stdout

Comment: well, I am seeing nothing, indicating that command_ seems empty. Which makes me wonder what was the original intent of the person who wrote this script...

Comment: Could it be a bug/typo?

Comment: The answer is that it just expands to whatever the custom variable `command_` is assigned to, as there's nothing special about this name or the underscore. As for why someone would write this, maybe the rest of the script has some clues. For example, if several variables have a trailing underscore, it might be a convention for script-local variables taking after the C++ convention for member variables.

Answer (score 1):

> What is ${command_} in a shell script

`${command_}` means to expand the variable named `command_` to it's value.

> What does this mean?

- `echo "docker run command"` - means to execute the command `echo` (possibly a builtin) with one argument `docker run command`.
- `echo ${command_}` - means to execute the command `echo` (possibly a builtin) with the result of expansion of the variable `command_` will undergo word splitting expansion and then the result will be passed as arguments to the `echo` command.

> there is an underscore after "command"

It doesn't matter - underscore is nothing special.

> command_ seems not to be defined elsewhere

That means that `${command_}` expansion will expand to an empty string, and the second `echo` will run with no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

echo command is used to print the arguments passed. But if argument has $ to it, it means it evaluates its value and prints the same.

Here, you shell script would be having a variable named "command_". It'll just find its value, if defined, and print it. If its not defined, nothing will be printed.